# Microsoft website pages appearing weird

Tags: browser

I bought a new machine on which I am trying to install MVC 3 but the [MVC 3 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) on the Microsoft website (and some other pages as well) look like this sometimes:

[image]

It looks like this on IE 9, Firefox 19.2 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m.

I remember many Microsoft website pages have appeared this way earlier to me. And then, after some days, they appeared alright again, and then they started appearing this way again.

Now, I could install other browsers and/or look up the source in Developer Tools or Firebug and get to the download button if I am lucky, but I want to find out what's happening. Anyone had this same experience?

Comment: I also have this problem occasionally on my Windows XP machine, but as davblayn suggests, this is not a programming related question.

Comment: Between your machine and site is set caching proxy that caches the page not correct. This first conclusion is, if the site in all browsers not display correctly and looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

I might be giving Microsoft too much credit, but the Microsoft pages should most certainly always work properly in Internet Explorer unless you have a local issue.  If you are getting this on any later version of IE, such as 9, likely it is an issue with you receiving the page as intended.

- Try [disabling Firefox's graphics acceleration](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/forum-response-disable-hardware-acceleration).  If this fixes, an update to your graphics hardware drivers may be in order.  (You mention you are having issues with Chrome as well ... I am not sure if Chrome has graphics acceleration available or enabled by default yet.)
- Check your IE addons to see if you have anything that could be malware, or possibly interfering.  Remove any toolbars, "coupon printers", PC diagnosis utilities, anything where the vendor can't be identified, and anything by online game companies.
  While you may be seeing issues in other browsers, I do believe IE addons can have effects systemwide.  You can also try running IE in safe mode - if you never see this issue in safe mode, this is certainly the issue.
- Check your Programs and Features to see if you have anything that could be spyware, malware, etc.  Remove any toolbars, "coupon printers", PC diagnosis utilities, anything where the vendor can't be identified, and anything by online game companies.
- Do you have anything that modifies your DNS settings like Comodo or Sendori installed?  Remove it and see if this reoccurs.
- Are you using a proxy server of any type?  Something may be wrong there.
- Does your ISP insert ads into non-encrypted HTTP traffic?  Your ISP may be trying to do this with this site, but not doing it properly.
- Try creating a new Windows user account.  If the issue goes away, copy everything to this new user account and delete your old one.